# Existing measurement error mitigation

Tags: ibm-q-experience, measurement, error-mitigation

Does IBM compute a measurement error mitigation calibration matrix that can be accessed from its device properties or somewhere else? Or does the user have to do that every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user has to create the error mitigation calibration matrix for their experiments. You could always just create the matrix for the subset of qubits you are experimenting on if you are sending your experiment to a larger device.